# Problem to run docker image

Tags: substrate-node-template, rust

I'm trying to run the image pulled from dockerhub: https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/gertdjali/escrow but doesn't work.

I ran the image locally by terminal './scripts/docker_run.sh' as described in this doc on git https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template. After I pushed this image to dockerhub, I pulled it from another machine(pc) and tried to run it but it doesn't work because when I try to connect it to the https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/explorer  says: Waiting to make a connection to the remote endpoint and finishing API initialization.
What should I do?
Can somebody pull my docker image and try to run it locally and then to connect to https://polkadot.js.org ?